# Schengen Visa: valid 24-09-2022 to 23-09-2023, multiple entry

Tags: schengen-visas, switzerland, multiple-entry

My Schengen visa was issued by Norway Consulate. It is a multiple entry type C valid from 24-09-22 To 23-09-23.

I have already spent a trip in Norway 24-09-22 to 7-10-22. Now I am back to Thailand.

I have a plan to Switzerland 25-04-23 to 07-05-23. I wonder that if I can use the same Schengen Visa for the upcoming trip (to Switzerland) or I have to do a new Schengen Visa?

Comment: Not sure what the question is. You have a valid visa, you've barely spent any time in the Schengen zone, what's the problem?

Comment: @chx I think it's safe to assume that the question is whether the visa can be used for a trip that does not include Norway.

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder that if I can use the same Schengen Visa for the upcoming trip (to Switzerland)

Yes, you may use the existing visa.

The visa is a multi-entry visa, so you may use it to enter the Schengen Area more than once while the visa is valid (2023-09-23).

Important is only that you may not remain **inside** the Schengen Area longer than 90 days in any 180 day period.

On the planed reentry date (2023-04-25), the previous day in the Schengen Area is more than 180 days. Therefore your day count will be 0 (zero), which means you could stay up to 90 days (**or** the last day the visa is valid, which ever is sooner), which would be 2023-07-23.

The requirement that your main destination is the country that issued the visa (Norway), is only true for your **first** visit (you are **not** required to visit Norway on any later visits).

Comment: Note that the immigration officials might still ask questions about the new itinerary. So in addition to the existing visa, you should think about (but not re-submit) the premise of the new trip. Do you have tickets, hotel bookings, spending money, medical insurance?

Comment: The latest allowable date of departure is 2023-07-23: six days in April, 31 in May, and 30 in June make a total of 67 days, leaving 23 days available in July.  Also, it's sufficient for the last day of presence to be 91 or more days in the past on the date of entry.

Comment: @phoog Yes. I should have added only 89 to the date calculator, since the first day is inclusive. Corrected. The second sentance is not relevent to the OP situation / question.

Comment: Thank you. Mark. Your answer is very clear and helpful. Thank again. Suchat